# Configuring vlc rtsp VoD server from config file

Tags: vlc-media-player, video-streaming, rtsp

I learned how to configure a RTSP server using vlc as follows:

```
# run vlc with the following command:
$ sudo vlc-wrapper --ttl 12 -vvv --color -I telnet --telnet-password videolan --rtsp-host 0.0.0.0 --rtsp-port 554
```

without sudo, it can not open up the socket (gives permission fault). So, I dare to run it as root.

And, try to access the telnet for configuring the VoD contents

```
$ telnet localhost 4212
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
VLC media player 2.0.4 Twoflower
Password:
Welcome, Master
> new Test vod enabled
new
> setup Test input test-video.mp4
setup
```

And, watch the video in browser

```
rtsp://<IP-to-server>/Test
```

What I want to know is, rather than accessing telnet for configuring rtsp VoD contents, 
is there any way for using a config file?

Answer (score 0):

You can execute

```
load /your/config/file
```

from the telnet session. That will execute all the instructions you're manually executing.

Anyway I don't know the command to execute them directly from the vlc server start line.

Answer (score 0):

in the version VLC media player 3.0.8 Vetinari there is a way to provide file as command option with `--vlm-conf <FILE>`, so the command would be:

```
sudo vlc-wrapper --ttl 12 -vvv --color -I telnet --telnet-password videolan --rtsp-host 0.0.0.0 --rtsp-port 554 --vlm-conf /your/config/file
```

Here is the doc: https://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation:Streaming_HowTo/VLM/#Configuration_Files